# Dual Boot Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 on iMac all-in-one

Tags: dual-boot

I am new to the Ubuntu scene so please bear with me. I have an iMac all in one that I installed Ubuntu on. It has 16gb of RAM, 1TB hard drive, AMD Juniper graphics card and i-7 8 core processor. I need to install Windows 10 and am wondering if it is possible to dual boot Windows with Ubuntu like Mac does with Boot Camp. I am currently running Windows 10 using VirtualBox, but would like to make full use of the resources on my computer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, although it would have been easier if you had installed Windows first.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Regarding Adroid Dev. How do you install Windows on a Mac? Only option I've seen is either VMware with Mac OS or Boot Camp. Is there a clean install for Windows only?

Comment: Windows 7+ supports UEFI, so all that's required to install it as the only OS on a Mac is to simply erase the hard drive and boot a Windows installer DVD/USB drive

Comment: @Panther 14.04.5 has 8 months left till EOL

Comment: Do you also have macOS installed? Related: [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6317/250300)

Comment: No. I clean installed Ubuntu. I tried re-installing macOS using the online backup, but it keeps failing.

Comment: Typing this from my newly installed Windows 10 on iMac! Worked like a charm to install once I got the bootup options to show. Thanks Android Dev! So far so good and loving it!